# Doubling slash with re.findall - Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall, slash

I wonder why re.findall returns a string by adding a escape slash in front of each slash. Can we force it to return a raw string that is without this doubling slash ?

**Example**

```
src='on <p>essia \( de faire \)</p>'
src = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',src)
print(src)
```

It returns:

```
['essia \\( de faire \\)']
```

But I would like to return:

```
['essia \( de faire \)']
```

Comment: Your expected and actual output looks same to me

Comment: oups....edited ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it prints entire list. Print its elements to get desired output.

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: src='on <p>essia \( de faire \)</p>'
   ...:

In [3]: src = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',src)

In [4]: print(src)
['essia \\( de faire \\)']

In [5]: print(src[0])
essia \( de faire \)
```